# IIS 7 and concurrent user requests for I/O extensive tasks

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, iis-7.5, load-balancing

We have a application which renders the images on the fly with dynamic data using WPF. Each individual Image generation takes approximately on average almost a second (1 sec) for a A4 Size Image generation.
The WorkerProcess shows the CPU usage 100% against these requests and the main items in its details are Isapi module.

We need to support 500 concurrent users for a client. How can I setup the IIS to handle that load balance and how can I reduce the CPU usage time?
Does multiple processor would work? Do I need to control this through the software or hardware would handle it automatically? Would Asynchronous requests help?

Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: Single server? How many cores? Is this an ASP.NET app, if so is it Forms or MVC? What version of ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes Single Server Dual Core (x64bit 8GB RAM), ASP.NET MVC3 App (.NET Framework 4) & C#